# Model estimation using ACF and PACF

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

Can anyone help in model estimation ? The following are the ACF,PACF and the plot of the sample respectively.

[image: plot of data]

[image: acf of data]

[image: pacf of model]

Comment: What is your question ? What is your problem ? What do you wanna achieve ? You have to be way more precise.

Comment: @JulienD.- which arma/arima model would fit best? I cannot make out from the acf graph..

Comment: also from the first plot, does it need differencing? or can it be considered stationary?

Comment: If your series is stationary (it might be nearly so), and you're not worried about the discreteness problem, then it may be approximately AR(1)xSAR(12). But I'd fit the AR(1) and see what the residual looked like.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the time series is not stationary from the first figure.
We should see the time series should have a constant mean and constant variance stable no trend ...

On the other hand, some hypothesis test can be employed, like Ljung-Box test, Augmented Dickey–Fuller (ADF) t-statistic test, Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin (KPSS) test

Answer (score 0):

Checking if your time series is stationary or not, see this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27332/how-to-know-if-a-time-series-is-stationary-or-non-stationary)

Checking which ARMA/ARIMA model to fit, see this [website](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can try fitting an AR(10) or AR(11) process. Run Ljung-Box tests for various lags on the residuals after fitting the model to see if the p-values of the Q statistic are less than a certain signifiance level (0.05 perhaps). If not, then your null hypothesis, i.e. that your fitted model describes the sample well, holds.